# Are Feroli (italy) and Olimp (Greece) legitimate brands of extra virgin olive oil?

Tags: italian-cuisine, olive-oil, greek-cuisine

Are Feroli (italy) and Olimp (Greece) legitimate brands of extra virgin olive oil? I could not find any information on the Internet that has been censored in China. They are being sold on PDD, one of the biggest online ecommerce platforms in China, and the platform is probably not indexed by search engines. Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by legitimate?

Comment: i can't find them beinh discussed on the internet censored in China. They are being sold online in China.

Comment: @Tim all I can find when googling for Feroli is online shops in Russia. For Olimp I found what looks like [the manufacturer's site](https://glgroup.gr/product/tm-olimp-black-label_en/) (along with a bunch of Russian e-shops)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make that much sense. Are you asking if they are real olive oil, or something else?

Comment: @Esther Do their extra virgin olive oil look trustworthy?

Comment: @gdd what doesn't make sense about asking if a brand for olive oil is legitimate?

Comment: I think Feroli is a knockoff. There is a Ferroli but they make heating oil as I recall from living in the area. Not sure about Olimp but there used to be (not sure if it still is) a Spanish brand "Olimpo" which we never bought because it had a reputation for not being particularly good quality.

Comment: @Tim I'm pretty sure he means "what does legitimate mean to you?"  the Olimp brand site describes the kind of olives used, where they are grown, and a unique process they use (soaking the olives before squeezing to remove bitterness). The site also have a number of different oils made with different olives and describes the taste of each. I'd assume it's actual olive oil, but I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: I'm just assuming that "legitimate" means "real olive oil from the place it says on the bottle" and answering from there.

Comment: "legitimate" probably refers to olive oil adulteration/fraud, something that's had a _lot_ of ink spilt on it

Comment: Olive oil fraud is a huge problem, it makes sense to ask if an olive oil brand is legitimate.

Answer (score 15):

[Olimp olive oil](https://glgroup.gr/product/tm-olimp-limited-edition_en/) is an olive oil produced by Gold Line Group, an European olive oil company.  Whether or not it is 100% Greek virgin olive oil is hard to determine; per the book [Extra Virginity](http://www.tommueller.co/extravirginigy), the majority of olive oil sold in the world is fraudulent, and there are no reliable international certifications.  But it's as likely to be real Greek olive oil as anything I would buy in the market here in the US.

Feroli, on the other hand, is not a company or brand of oil that exists outside China and Russia.  Sometimes Chinese importers relabel real olive oil with brand names they feel are more marketable inside China, but your odds are poor.  It is more likely that this is not real Italian olive oil, and it may not be olive oil at all.

Comment: Thanks. How is sam' member mark extra virgin olive oil?

Comment: funny enough, the two are sold by.the same Chinese retailer on PDD. The retailer also sells Aranta (Spain) extra pomace olive oil, which is also listed on the website of Gold Line Group

Comment: I suspect that the Gold Line Group is good at exporting things to China, something that not many European manufaturers are.

Comment: Feroli, olimp, aranta have similar packaging styles. I cant find feroli on the website of Gold Line Group

Comment: It's not one of theirs.  And that tin is a fairly standard size/shape for olive oil, so the similarity doesn't mean anything.

Comment: How is sam club's  member mark extra virgin olive oil?

Comment: For what it's worth, @Tim, the Olimp [web page](https://glgroup.gr/) claims it is "Olive oil [...] made only from natural olive oil". That is either an error or an actual admission that they are not producing olive oil, but are somehow refining it. Olive oil isn't "made from olive oil", it is made from _olives_. As a Greek living outside Greece, my simple rule of thumb for Greek olive oil is if the bottle doesn't have any text in Greek, then it is likely a crappy tourist trap. This isn't always true, and some excellent oil is produced for export only, but it is a helpful rule of thumb.

Comment: @terdon thanks.  I am going to cancel the order ...

Comment: The web site is clearly a direct machine translation into English.  I don't know that I'd read too much into the wording there.

Comment: @terdon I bet some Chinese companies are about to take note of your comment and will add some meaningless and grammatically garbled Greek text to their labels...

Comment: @terdon No idea about Greek olive oil exports specifically, but in general, most exports of liquids like wine and oil are in wholesale quantities, so in tank containers containing (tens of) thousands of litres of the stuff. Bottling into retail packaging then takes place close to the target market. There's no point shipping the bottles, unless it's a niche specialty product. So South African or Californian wine sold in Europe is almost always bottled in Europe, and I would be surprised if European oil in China wasn't handled the same way. The bottle and label is going to be made in China.

Answer (score 10):

I can’t say anything for sure about this particular brand, but there are a few phrases in your pictures that are likely questionable:

- ‘Olive Oil Product’ : means that it’s something made with olive oil, not that it is exclusively olive oil.  I suspect that it is a blended oil
- ‘Product of Italy’ : means that it has been in Italy.  It usually means that it was packaged in Italy from imported oil
- ‘100% quality’ : means absolutely nothing
- ‘100% natural’ : is used on so many things that it’s effectively meaningless (there have been some lawsuits in the US over this claim, and the courts decided that High Fructose Corn Syrup can be considered ‘natural’ depending on how it’s made)

In the US, there will always be an ingredient list which will show what type of oil (or oils) it actually is, and there is usually some statement about where the olives are grown (Such as ‘packaged in Italy from Italian, Greek, and Tunisian olives’). Unlike the ingredient lists, those statements are not required to be in any particular order, so it’s possible that it is primarily Tunisian olives with enough Italian and Greek ones for them to be able to confuse the issue.

Some other counties also have labeling laws, but China may not be one of them.

Comment: Thanks. Which brands would you choose,  olimp (Greece), sam's club member's mark (Spain), star (spain), or ebates (Spain)? The last two.with only half a year before expiration

Comment: I honestly have no idea.  ‘Best by’ (what you called ‘expiration’) is something that the manufacturer estimates, but may mean absolutely nothing.  How the item has been stored (eg, at what temperature and constant vs varying) plays a huge factor of when oil starts to have issues.  I would recommend buying from a store with high turnover more than anything else.

Comment: typo: ebates (spain) -> ebest (spain)

Comment: Yes best by, but it is called "expiry" here. All the four have similar prices per unit, and the last two are near their expiry. EVOO is expensive in China, and products of legitimate brands are affordable only when they approach their expiry, and such products come from other countries because they are hard to sell there but have high turnover rates here.

Comment: The Sam's Club Member's Mark is olive oil, but it's pomace oil -- the dregs of olive oil -- and not virgin olive oil.

Answer (score 5):

Searching for results in Italian about Feroli olive oil or Feroli olio oliva returns 0 results.

Also the Italian flag with the "product of Italy" on the packages seems like a sloppy graphic job.

I am not sure what you mean with legitimate, but at least it doesn't sound like an olive oil made in Italy.

It's probably a marketing strategy to make it sound more appealing to the average customer, like calling any wine Chateau something, to make it sound like a French wine.

Comment: "Olive oil product" screams "we can't legally call this olive oil" to me